# Usage of data entities to exchange between client and microservices (asp.core)

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

Usually i create dto's to get data from microservice (WebApi) to client (MVC).
But sometimes it's cumbersome to duplicate structure of data entity to dto, especially if entity has multiple fields and many embedded relationships. 
So i have to duplicate fields and relations.

- Can i use data entity instead of dto?
- I use a special assembly for dto's to be exchanged between client (MVC) and given microservice. Should my data entities live in this assembly?

Comment: Can you add a concrete example to your question?

Comment: If you find that you are creating multiple dto classes, check that you are making the most of inheritance, as this could save duplication across classes. Where you store the classes is up to you, but consider looking at this https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common complaint that derives from not understanding the concept of bounded contexts. Because you're deep in the code, you just see two things that *look* like the same thing, and you have had, like all developers, the idea beaten into your brain that you should not repeat yourself (DRY).

However, the key word above is that the two things *look* the same. They are in fact *not* the same, and that is the critical salient point. They are representations of domain objects from *different* contexts (data store and application layer, for example). If you use the same object, you are tightly coupling those contexts to the point where they're now inseparable. As such, the very concept of having multiple layers becomes moot.

A related concept here is anti-corruption layers. This is a layer you add to your application to facilitate communication between two different application contexts or domains. An API is a form of anti-corruption layer. Again, because you're building all the apps, it seems like they're all the same thing. However, imagine your MVC app as a third-party application being built by someone else to consume your API. Should *they* use *your* entities directly? No. They probably would have their own entity classes and their own data store. The DTO your API uses provides a way for these two different applications to communicate via a common language. If you use your entity classes directly, then any change to your data, necessitates a change to your API, which in turn necessitates a change to any consumers of your API. Imagine if Google changed a database column, and because of that, every single developer using their API(s) had to immediately make changes to their own applications or they would break.

In short, just because two classes *look* the same, doesn't mean they *are* the same. Your entity and your DTO are each representations of a concept *in different contexts*, and therefore you need and should have both.